# java cloneing error

Tags: java, clone

I have a method that tries to clone an instance of a class (B) i have writen.This method is being called in class A so this method is not in the same class as the class i'm trying to clone (B). The class i'm trying to clone impliments colneable. when i try to compile my code i get an error message that reads "clone() has protected access in Java.lang.Object. Why might this be happing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be happening because you are trying to call the clone() method outside its allowed access. For you to be able to call it, the class that is calling it should extend directly from Object, or belong to the Same Package, or be Object. More information here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want some code inside class A to clone an instance of class B, then either place A and B in the same package, or broaden the access to B.clone() by making it public (rather than leaving it protected-scope.)

Furthermore, I would refer you to the book [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) by Josh Bloch. I found a PDF of Chapter three [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can only access protected members of a type in a different package if the compile-time type of the expression you're referencing it through is either your own class or a subclass.

Check this [link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2).

Comment: so the problem is that A is not a sublcass of B?

Comment: @David ... and A and B are in different packages.